# Add class with ng-class on click to parent from child

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, html

I have following problems. I need to set `active` class to an parent `div` on click from child div that is inside that parent. To illustrate I will provide a code. And omit parts of it for readability.

> HTML

```
<div class="offer__container" ng-repeat="price in settingsPrices">
  ...
  <div class="offer__container__cta hvr-sweep-to-right">Select</div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.selected {
    border: 2px solid #ffbe10;
}
.selected-cta {
    background-color: #ffbe10;
}
```

As you can see i have `offer__container` that fetches some data and does ng-repeat, i need to be able to on click from `offer__container__cta` add the `active` style to parent container and keep track of as if i click another `div` rendered via ng-repeat it should take the active style and transfer it to that div. Preferably I would also like to set certain style on `offer__container__cta` such as make it also active.

I am open to all solutions.

Edit: Here is the picture of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: You forget to add the css. You should start from there.

Comment: You are right my bad i have added the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ng-class` to dynamically add classes according to expressions.
create a new property in an object and assign it false using `ng-init` initially.Then on the click change the boolean value to opposite boolean

```
<div class="offer__container" ng-repeat="price in settingsPrices" ng-class="{'active': price.activePrice}">
  ...
  <div ng-init="price.activePrice = false" class="offer__container__cta hvr-sweep-to-right" ng-click="changeCls(price,$index)">Select</div>
</div>
```

add this to `ng-click` function

```
var globalIndex = 0;
$scope.changeCls = function(price, index) {
    price.activePrice = !price.activePrice;
    $scope.settingsPrices[globalIndex].activePrice = false;
    globalIndex = index;

}
```

Comment: Works but It does not take off the style from other divs.

Comment: Works like a charm :) If I could thank you milion times I would.

Comment: One more question you can see the picture i provided how would i go about setting that style on click in similar fashion to what you have provided on parent `div`

Answer (score 1):

I've created a fiddle for you [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3enyzc0q/2/) and below is the code. You just create a boolean flag to your model and set it as active or inactive depending on your needs. Also, every selection clears the previous selection.

It is good to create a separate flag in your model instead of inline variable in template as it keep the template clean from such flags.

I'm using `selected` class but you can replace it with your class that you would like to give to the container div element.

CSS:

```
.selected{
  color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
  <div class="offer__container" data-ng-class="{ selected: price.isSelected}" ng-repeat="price in vm.settingsPrices">
  {{price.amount}}
  <button class="offer__container__cta hvr-sweep-to-right" data-ng-click="vm.select(price)">Select</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.settingsPrices = [{
        amount: 99,
      isSelected: false
    }, 
    {
        amount: 10,
      isSelected: false
    }
    ];

    vm.select = function(price){
        vm.removeAllSelection();
     price.isSelected = true;
    }

    vm.removeAllSelection = function(){
        angular.forEach(vm.settingsPrices, function(value, key) {
             value.isSelected = false;
                });
    }
}

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the data I'm fetching I only get limited data.

Comment: that's fine, you can add this new member when you fetch your data. Or last solution is to use inline variable!

Comment: @kadza I've updated the fiddle to clear previous selection(s).

Comment: @kadza also please add information like your comment above in question itself for your future questions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```html
<div class="offer__container" ng-repeat="price in settingsPrices" ng-class="{active: activePrice === price.amount}">
  ...
  <div class="offer__container__cta hvr-sweep-to-right" ng-click="activePrice = price.amount">Select</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sets the `selected` class on all the `divs` I need it only to be active on one div at the time.

Comment: Are you sure you tested my code? I see another answer which will have the behavior from your comment above.

Comment: I did it outlines all the divs with the style.